# Display comments on homepage of twenty seventeen theme

Tags: comments, theme-twenty-seventeen

I would like to display comments on a static [home page of a site](http://disputeit.org) using the twenty seventeen theme. I have configured it on in the settings and on the page but nothing gets displayed.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to create front-page.php file in the child theme of seventeen theme on your site and add following modified code in it.

```
<?php
/**
 * The front page template file
 *
 * If the user has selected a static page for their homepage, this is what will
 * appear.
 * Learn more: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php // Show the selected frontpage content.
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'front-page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            endwhile;
        else : // I'm not sure it's possible to have no posts when this page is shown, but WTH.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' );
        endif; ?>

        <?php
        // Get each of our panels and show the post data.
        if ( 0 !== twentyseventeen_panel_count() || is_customize_preview() ) : // If we have pages to show.

            /**
             * Filter number of front page sections in Twenty Seventeen.
             *
             * @since Twenty Seventeen 1.0
             *
             * @param $num_sections integer
             */
            $num_sections = apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_front_page_sections', 4 );
            global $twentyseventeencounter;

            // Create a setting and control for each of the sections available in the theme.
            for ( $i = 1; $i < ( 1 + $num_sections ); $i++ ) {
                $twentyseventeencounter = $i;
                twentyseventeen_front_page_section( null, $i );
            }

    endif; // The if ( 0 !== twentyseventeen_panel_count() ) ends here. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: I am not good with the computer. Could you create sample front-page.php file in the child theme of seventeen theme for me?
This way, everybody will copy that when they use seventy seventeen.

Answer (score 0):

You can search Google to create a Child Theme OR
Just replace the current text in front-page.php with above
It works either way

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255540)